# Number not dividing in loop

Tags: c++

I just started using C++, and I'm usually comfortable with Java, but I've run into a logical error.

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Number: " << endl;
    cin >> number;
    while (number != 0 || number > 0) {
        number/3;
        cout << number << endl;
    }
    if (number = 0) {
        cout << "True" << endl;

    }
    else {
        cout << "False" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to check if the number inputted is divisible by 3, but it just keeps printing the number on repeat instead of dividing? Why is `number/3;` not working?

Comment: `number/3;` wouldn't do anything in Java, either.

Comment: you are not updating number after computation, you need to assign number new value by updating "number = number/3"

Comment: `if (number = 0) {` sets number to 0 then compares if it's not 0 to output true otherwise it outputs false.

Answer (score 4):

Several issues:

This line:

```
if (number = 0) {
```

Is assigning 0 to number, not comparing with it.  Then the entire expression is evaluated as `false` and the `else` clause will execute and print `"False"` no matter the input.  If you want to compare, you use `==` operator.

But your main algorithm has an issue:

```
   while (number != 0 || number > 0) {
        number/3;
        cout << number << endl;
    }
```

First, `number/3` doesn't do anything because you aren't assigning the result to anything.  Better:

```
number = number / 3;
```

But it doesn't matter since all integer division does is drop the remainder.  So even if you make this fix, that loop will reduce any positive value of `number` to `0` anyway.  If the user types 17, the algorithm will reduce `number` to the following:

```
number = 17 / 3;  // prints 5
number = 5 / 2;   // prints 2
number = 2 / 3;   // prints 0
```

And then your code would still think 17 is divisible by 3.

And finally, if you just want to see if a number "is divisible by", use the modulo, `%`, operator. This computes the remainder of a division expression. Works with positive and negative numbers.

```
if (number % 3 == 0) {
    printf("number is divisible by 3\n");
}
```

But I think the algorithm you are after is effectively this:

```
int result = number / 3;
if (result*3 == number) {
    printf("number is divisible by 3\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `number = number / 3;` and `if (number == 0)`.
It should be same as `Java`

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    cout << "Number: " << endl;
    cin >> number;
    while (number != 0 || number > 0) {
        number = number/3;
        cout << number << endl;
    }
    if (number == 0) {
        cout << "True" << endl;

    }
    else {
        cout << "False" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I type "7" as input into this program, it still prints True.

Comment: Yes, that's a logical issue. His logic of the code is not correct! I think it should be fixed by himself. I just mentioned the syntax issues. @selbie

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign number/3 to a variable in order to change it's value. This can simply be done by stating:
`number = number/3;`

or in some languages:

`number /= 3;`

Answer (score -2):

change number/3;
to
number = number/3;

Comment: A good answer would explain why. For this problem the explanation is pretty short.

Comment: Answer from 8 minutes before says the same thing.